# how do I custom design for menu item?

Tags: magento, drop-down-menu

I have menu in which there are two levels. After I added the third and fourth level of categories from the back end, I want the third sub-category in the menu to be displayed differently I want to change its appearance. Can i do it in back end custom design? Or where should I look for the code? I have tried editing the top menu p html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should edit the relevant PHTML file in order to do this.

Sometimes you will have to edit menu.js as well written in prototype. if you are not familiar with it use a jQuery code.